# What should my AngularJS app do when the browser refreshes?

Tags: angularjs, page-refresh

I'm finishing my first serious project with AngularJS. Everything works fine but I'm currently stuck.

What if the user refreshes the browser (e.g., F5)?

The traditional web application is run server-side, where the HTML is generated. Here, updating your browser does not generate many problems because all the data is on the server: for example, a shopping cart.

In my application, AngularJS is the only page. I hardly go back to my server until the user finishes doing what he came to do.

So what I can do to get past this problem and not lose the user's progress when updating the browser?

Any help Will be appreciated.

Comment: If you absolutely do not want to call your server once in a while, you could try looking at HTML5 Local Storage and see if it can fit your need (if you do not need < IE8 support).

Comment: @rnrneverdies have you seen my answer

Comment: yes but i need time to research and test it, be patient. :P

Answer (score 0):

i think local storage should be the best option to store user info or other data.

use LocalStorageModule dependecies in main module like this:

```
var masterJs = angular.module('masterJs', [
    'LocalStorageModule',   
    'ngRoute',

]);
```

assume that i have to store some data after login in login controller. so we set data in local storage like this:

```
angular.module('masterJs')
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $http, $window,     localStorageService) {


    $scope.login_dev = function(auth){
      var url = 'http://masterjs.in/users/login';
      $http({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data:auth
      })

      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         localStorageService.clearAll();
         localStorageService.set('id', data.data._id);
         localStorageService.set('token_id', data.token);
       //var token = localStorageService.get('token_id');
         var owner_id = localStorageService.get('id');
         $location.path('/account/account-overview');
      })

      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       alert("error");
       $location.path('/login_dev')
      });

    }
});
```

and put angular-locale-Storage.js in your app and refrence them on index.html page.you can get angular-local-Storage.js in following link and you can go through more detail using this link.

see [this](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) link or [this](https://github.com/agrublev/angularLocalStorage) link